# Dynamically pick inheritance when instantiating a class?

Tags: python, inheritance

```
class classA:
    def common(self):
        print('A')

class classB:
    def common(self):
        print('B')

class classC:
    def workflow(self):
        print('Do something')
        self.common()
        print('Do something else')


A = classC() # Here I want to create classC that inherits from classA
A.workflow()
assert isinstance(A, classA)

B = classC() # Here I want to create classC that inherits from classB
B.workflow()
assert isinstance(B, classB)
```

In this example I have `classA` and `classB` that both implement a function `common()` that outputs a different value. I'd like to have `classC` inherit from one of those classes such that `workflow()` will have a slightly different behavior depending on which `common()` method it inherits. The main goal of this is to have one `workflow()` method where the result of `self.common()` changes depending on the inheritance.

How can I choose which class `classC` inherits from when I instantiate `classC`?

Answer (score 0):

You can't pick a different parent class for individual objects; *classes* handle inheritance. That said, you can create a *new* class on demand by using `type` directly. You won't be using `classC` directly, but a child class that inherits from both `classC` and the appropriate one of `classA` and `classB`, treating the two as mix-in classes.

```
a = type("pick-a-name", (classC, classA), {})()
b = type("pick-a-name", (classC, classB), {})()
```

You'll note there's an extra expense here, in that every time you try to instantiate an object, you have to create a new class first. You might as well
define the child classes right away.

```
class Ca(classC, classA):
    pass

class Cb(classC, classB):
    pass
```